# Why is mySwiper is not defined but still works

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have swiperjs working except I am trying to access its methods to apply a slide centering hack. To do that I need to access its object but for some reason it tells me undefined even though the swiper works.

Swiper set is:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('#design', {
       slidesPerView: 3,
       spaceBetween: 30,
       loop: false,
       observer: true,
       observeParents: true,
       observeSlideChildren: true,
       preventClicksPropagation: false,
       centeredSlides: true,
       centeredSlidesBounds: true,
       centerInsufficientSlides: true,
       navigation: {
         nextEl: '.swiper-design #swiper-button-feature-next',
         prevEl: '.swiper-design #swiper-button-feature-prev',
       },
       breakpoints: {
        1024: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 30,
        },
        768: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 30,
        },
        640: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
          spaceBetween: 20,
        },
        320: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
          spaceBetween: 10,
        }
      },
      on: {
        init: function () {
          console.log('swiper initialized');
          console.log(mySwiper);
        },
      }
     });
```

I am wanting to implement a hack along these lines, https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/2081#issuecomment-296781831 so I can center swipers that have only one slide.

Any thoughts as to what is up here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The init function within the swiper doesn't **know** that variable exists.

**So change**

```
init: function () {
```

**to**

```
init: function (mySwiper) {
```